# AS3 Text Input accents

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I create an AS3 TextField set to Input mode dynamically through code, but when the user tries to input some special characters (eg. á à é è í ì ó ò ú ù ç) they simply do not appear on the TextInput.

Copying and pasting them to the textfield works, but I'd prefer if the user could directly type them.

Here's a quick test demonstrating this:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;

    public class TextInput extends Sprite
    {
        public function TextInput()
        {
            super();

            var t:TextField = new TextField;
            t.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
            addChild(t);
        }
    }
}
```

This creates a textfield where the user can type, but I can't type special characters like à.

Many thanks.

Comment: if copying and pasting them into the textfield works, then it's not a font embedding issue, so there's nothing stopping people from just typing the special character in there. i did a quick test, and it was fine for me. can you give more info?

Comment: When you say "they simply do not appear on the TextInput" do you mean nothing happens when you type (no characters are added to the TextInput)? Or are you getting some strange characters instead? Are you using the TextInput `restrict` property?

Comment: I'm not using restrict property. Let me write a quick test and post code here.

Comment: Are you embedding the proper set of glyphs?

Comment: I had no problems running the sample code. Have you tested it on a (clean) new project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can paste it into the Input field, you should be able to type it.

If you start a new Flash document, using the same font as you are above create an Input textfield on the stage with the following settings:

Embed the normal glyphs
[image]

Embed the extended latin glyphs
[image]

And this should work, as:
[image]

Now if all this works, it might have something to do with the way the class is written.

Writing classes that embeds fonts is frankly a pain. Make sure you embed the font in the library and export it for action script:

[image]

Following that, you need to use the following code:

```
// The name of the font class
var _font:Calibri = new Calibri();

var _textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
_textFormat.font = _font.fontName;
_textFormat.size = 16;

// For some weird reason the ordering here is important. I remember mucking around with this for ages for an old project. EmbedFonts must come last
var _textField:TextField = new TextField();
_textField.defaultTextFormat = _textFormat;
_textField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
_textField.embedFonts = true;

addChild(_textField);
```

And that should have it all working:

[image]

** EDIT **
To those using FlashDevelop, etc you can use the following method:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {

    [Embed(source='assets/HOBOSTD.OTF', fontName='_hobo', embedAsCFF="false")] public static const HOBO:Class;

    public function Main() {
        var _font:Font = new HOBO() as Font;

        var _textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        _textFormat.font = _font.fontName;
        _textFormat.size = 22;

           var _textField:TextField = new TextField();

        _textField.embedFonts = true;
        _textField.defaultTextFormat = _textFormat;
        _textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        _textField.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
        _textField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;

        addChild(_textField);
    }
}
```

And you will get the following:

[image]

Now note, the font file must be either relative to your project, or the source can point to the C:\windows\font folder if you choose. In the above example, I copied the font to my assets folder.

Comment: I am not using Flash CSX, I'm using a Pure Actionscript 3 project (I use FlashBuilder, can be created with FlashDevelop as well). Embedding fonts using the common embed doesn't work either. Anyway to embed those glyphs using the [Embed] meta tag?

Comment: Does not work for me, but some Windows users can get it to work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, so it's still not working? Is the same thing happening? Did you try the above code? What os are you using?